# Component/Strategy Pattern in C++, Design and Implementation

Tags: c++, polymorphism, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, strategy-pattern

I have a C++ project, using OpenFrameworks for rendering, that bounces a couple of balls (circles) around in a window. They are implemented using the Component Pattern (sometimes referred to as Strategy Pattern) to encapsulate look and behavior respectively. This makes the look (here: Amiga Ball) and the behavior (here: bouncing with gravity) exchangeable at runtime.

[image: Good old Amiga Balls bouncing in C++]

The pattern itself is inspired by the Component Pattern chapter in [Robert Nystrom's book Game Programming Patterns](https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/component.html).
Upon pressing a key the behavior of "bouncing with gravity" is exchanged with "bouncing with no-gravity" (the creativity of this is probably the reason I'm programming and not designing).
I want to implement the pattern using smart pointers (in this case unique_ptr would do because there is no sharing and one component object is always uniquely held by a GameObject).
There are several "ugly" parts in my code related to the use of unique_ptr and the fact that I use polymorphism for the components but seemingly sometimes have to treat them as derived-class objects instead of base-class.

I would like to know if it a good and feasible design and implementation w.r.t. design and implementation of the pattern in general, and the use of smart pointers in particular.

Note: I didn't care for const-correctness here although I should have. So I'm sure there is lots of const to be put in there, but please don't bash me simply for that, except it plays into the other problems.

So here goes...

We have a class GameObject holding the minimal information any object on the screen should have:
GameObject.hpp:

```cpp
    class GameObject {
    public:
        float x;
        float y;

        GameObject(unique_ptr<PhysicsComponent> physics, unique_ptr<GraphicsComponent> graphics);
        GameObject();
        GameObject(float x, float y);

        void update();
        void draw();
        void setPhysicsComponent(unique_ptr<PhysicsComponent> pc);
        void setGraphicsComponent(unique_ptr<GraphicsComponent> pc);
        unique_ptr<PhysicsComponent>& getPhysicsComponent();
        unique_ptr<GraphicsComponent>& getGraphicsComponent();

    private:
        unique_ptr<PhysicsComponent> physics_;
        unique_ptr<GraphicsComponent> graphics_; 
    };
```

GameObject.cpp:

```cpp
GameObject::GameObject(unique_ptr<PhysicsComponent> physics, unique_ptr<GraphicsComponent> graphics) : physics_(move(physics)), graphics_(move(graphics)) {}

GameObject::GameObject() {}

GameObject::GameObject(float x, float y) : x(x), y(y) {}

void GameObject::update(){
    physics_->update(*this);
}

void GameObject::draw() {
    graphics_->draw(*this);
}

void GameObject::setPhysicsComponent(unique_ptr<PhysicsComponent> pc) {
    physics_ = std::move(pc);
}

void GameObject::setGraphicsComponent(unique_ptr<GraphicsComponent> gc) {
    graphics_ = std::move(gc);
}

std::unique_ptr<GraphicsComponent>& GameObject::getGraphicsComponent() {
    return graphics_;
}

std::unique_ptr<PhysicsComponent>& GameObject::getPhysicsComponent() {
    return physics_;
}
```

Then there is the base class for components (in this case lets focus on physics components, as the graphics components are equivalent):

```cpp
class GameObject;

class PhysicsComponent {
    public:
        virtual ~PhysicsComponent() {std::cout<<"~PhysicsComponent()"<<std::endl;}
        virtual void update(GameObject& obj) = 0;

        void setXSpeed(float xs) {xSpeed = xs;};
        float getXSpeed() {return xSpeed;};
        void setYSpeed(float ys) {ySpeed = ys;};
        float getYSpeed() {return ySpeed;};

    protected:
        float ySpeed;
        float xSpeed;
};
```

A concrete implementation of the PhysicsComponent looks like this:

```cpp
class GravityBouncePhysicsComponent : public PhysicsComponent {
    public:
        virtual ~GravityBouncePhysicsComponent()  {std::cout<<"~GravityBouncePhysicsComponent()"<<std::endl;};
        GravityBouncePhysicsComponent();
        GravityBouncePhysicsComponent(float radius, float xSpeed, float ySpeed, float yAccel);
        virtual void update(GameObject& obj);
        void setRadius(float r) {radius = r;};
        float getRadius() {return radius;};
    private:
        // Physics
        float yAcceleration;
        float radius;
};
```

In the GravityBouncePhysicsComponent.cpp the empty constructor creates such a component with random values for xSpeed and ySpeed (living in the base class) and yAcceleration (making only sense in the derived component class).
And then there is another one called FloatBouncePhysicsComponent with similar code.

Now I want to use these classes in the main program, which happens to be the ofApp class in OpenFrameworks. The header file looks like this (some insignificant stuff omitted):

```cpp
class ofApp : public ofBaseApp{
    public:
        void setup();
        void update();
        void draw();

        void keyPressed(int key);
        // ... lots of other event functions for mouse etc.

    private:
        std::vector<GameObject> balls;
        GameObject createAmigaBall(float x, float y);

        // more variables and some methods here ...

};
```

Now in the ofApp.cpp file it starts getting ugly. For example in a helper function to create a new ball it looks like this:

```cpp
GameObject ofApp::createAmigaBall(float x, float y) {
    GameObject go(x,y); // create an empty GameObject on the stack at position x,y
    go.setGraphicsComponent(std::make_unique<AmigaBallGraphicsComponent>());

    if(gravity) {
        go.setPhysicsComponent(std::make_unique<GravityBouncePhysicsComponent>());
        float r = (static_cast<AmigaBallGraphicsComponent*>((go.getGraphicsComponent()).get()))->getRadius();
        (static_cast<GravityBouncePhysicsComponent*>((go.getPhysicsComponent()).get()))->setRadius(r);
    } else {
        go.setPhysicsComponent(std::make_unique<FloatBouncePhysicsComponent>());
        float r = (static_cast<AmigaBallGraphicsComponent*>((go.getGraphicsComponent()).get()))->getRadius();
        (static_cast<FloatBouncePhysicsComponent*>((go.getPhysicsComponent()).get()))->setRadius(r);
    }

    return go; // calls the copy constructor for return value, so we have no dangling pointers or refs
}
```

Here the AmigaBallGraphicsComponent empty constructor generates a random radius. This radius belongs into this derived class because it is certainly not in every GraphicsComponent.
However, this leads to having to clumsily extract the radius from the generated component with ugly casts and accessing the raw pointer, only to do that again to set the same radius in the GravityBouncePhysicsComponent.

And if you think THAT was ugly, check out this snippet:

```cpp
void ofApp::keyPressed(int key){
    if(key == 'a') {
        if(gravity) {
            for(int i=0; i<balls.size(); i++) {
                unique_ptr<GravityBouncePhysicsComponent> opc (static_cast<GravityBouncePhysicsComponent*>((balls[i].getPhysicsComponent()).release()));
                float r = opc->getRadius();
                float xs = opc->getXSpeed();
                float ys = opc->getYSpeed();
                balls[i].setPhysicsComponent(std::make_unique<FloatBouncePhysicsComponent>(r,xs,ys));
            }
        } else {
                // similar code for the non-gravity case omitted ...
            }
        }
        gravity =!gravity;
    }
}
```

And, as if that casting-to-derived-classes stuff was not enough, it turned out that this piece of code does not work

```cpp
auto gc = std::make_unique<AmigaBallGraphicsComponent>();
go.setGraphicsComponent(gc);
```

while this one does. What the ... ?

```cpp
go.setGraphicsComponent(std::make_unique<AmigaBallGraphicsComponent>());
```

Shouldn't this be exactly the same?

Thanks in advance for any insights on this whole mess (or is it?).

Comment: Please post the actual error your compiler is reporting to you.

Comment: `go.setGraphicsComponent(std::move(gc));`. The whole point of `std::unique_ptr` is that it is movable-only to ensure unique ownership.

Comment: There is no error. The code works. My question clearly asks if the general design and implementation of the pattern is well done in C++ and if my use of smart pointers is feasible.

Comment: Returning a reference to `unique_ptr` in your getters doesn't make much sense. If the purpose of the getter is to grant read-write access to the object while keeping ownership of it, just return a reference.

Comment: @Martin I'm answering your bottom-most question: your two last snippets are *not* the same, the first one tries to copy the `std::unique_ptr` instead of moving it and that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Rinat: You mean a pointer to a PhysicsComponent? A reference to what, should the getter return?

Comment: @Quentin: thanks! Of course the assignment operator calls the copy constructor, which would violate the uniqueness. Would it work to create the component variavle gc in a different way, e.g. by a constructor?

Comment: @Martin `std::unique_ptr<GraphicsComponent>& GameObject::getGraphicsComponent() ` Why do you return a unique_ptr here? Is there a possibility that a user of this method will move from it?

Comment: @Rinat: To be frank, I didn't think too much on that one. Usually, a getter-function simply returns that type of the member it is supposed to "get". So I assumed using a unique_ptr<GraphicsComponent> would be the right return type, because the component also has this type. I've impemented it with raw pointers too, and there the return type was PhysicsComponent* of course. I used a reference because not using a reference gave me a compiler error. I probably should have taken that as a warning ;) ... What do you suggest how the getter-function should look?

Comment: If you don't intend for the user to be able to take ownership over your unique_ptr, just return a reference to the actual component.

Comment: Thanks, Rinat. That would be a better way to do it. I guess the answer below also solves this. Totally didn't see you could use template functions for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think most of your issues come from the fact that you're letting the ownership (`std::unique_ptr`) and type erasure (polymorphism) concerns bleed out of your API, which requires a lot of irrelevant lifetime management and downcasting on the user side. `getGraphicsComponent` (and its buddies) could be implemented like this:

```
template <class DerivedGraphicsComponent = GraphicsComponent>
auto &getGraphicsComponent() {
    return static_cast<DerivedGraphicsComponent &>(*graphics_);
}
```

This enables you to write:

```
float r = go.getGraphicsComponent<AmigaBallGraphicsComponent>().getRadius();
```

Or to omit the `<AmigaBallGraphicsComponent>` and receive a plain `GraphicsComponent &`.

You do lose the ability for `GameObject` to revoke ownership of one of its components, and return it through a `std::unique_ptr`, but it doesn't look like you actually need it. The snippet where you use that feature ends up doing:

```
balls[i].setPhysicsComponent(std::make_unique<FloatBouncePhysicsComponent>(r,xs,ys));
```

... which destroys the previous component anyway through `graphics_`'s move-assignment operator. If you *do* need that functionality, by all means add another function:

```
template <class DerivedGraphicsComponent = GraphicsComponent>
auto releaseGraphicsComponent() {
    return std::unique_ptr<DerivedGraphicsComponent>(
        static_cast<DerivedGraphicsComponent *>(graphics_.release())
    );
}
```

Comment: Hey, thats quite some sufficiently advanced technology there... almost like...magic! :P. Thanks a lot man! This makes the code SO much more elegant and kills all casts (well shifts the type decision to the template parameter). Great stuff. I did need to switch to C++14 (which isn't easy to find with OpenFrameworks projects), but that did the trick. Never would have thought of template functions, although such things are used in C# all the time. Hidden in plain sight I guess.

Comment: @Martin while we're juggling templates, I suggest you replace `static_cast` with `dynamic_cast` in debug builds to catch downcasting errors -- otherwise they'll just trigger UB. Writing that cleanly is left as an exercise :)

Comment: Hey, good point. I replaced the static_cast with dynamic_cast in the template getter functions and it compiles and works like a charm. I guess you mean illegal downcasting errors, but wouldn't those fail to compile with static_cast? What do you mean with "UB"?

Comment: @Martin If you write a completely impossible cast, it will indeed fail to compile. A downcast to a given derived class will compile, but at runtime the actual object behind that base class reference might well be of *another* derived class (`BouncingHotdogGraphicsComponent`), in which case the cast is invalid.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` checks for this and will throw an exception (or return `nullptr` in its pointer variant), while `static_cast` won't check anything and happily cast to the wrong type, triggering Undefined Behaviour. UB means that, formally, you're leaving the realm of well-functioning C++ as defined by its standard, and informally that your program will just malfunction in various (sometimes comically absurd) ways, since it is now executing code that makes no sense (in this case, manipulating an object that doesn't actually exist).

Comment: And the behavior of static_cast and dynamic cast in the face of Hot Dogs would be? Do I get clean exceptions with dynamic, and segmentation faults with static?

Comment: The tradeoff is that `static_cast` is as fast as can be, but does no runtime check whatsoever (hence "static", i.e. compile-time), while `dynamic_cast` will catch and report your error in a well-defined manner but requires runtime machinery to do that (namely, the classes must be polymorphic, and the cast itself has a cost). Edit: a segmentation fault is indeed a possible outcome of UB, but it can also corrupt memory, execute code in a nonsensical way, or even seem to work fine until you nudge it the wrong way. No guarantees :)

Comment: Great explanation, thanks! I've implemented it and one small question remains. The solution includes auto deduced return types. Is there any possibility to separate these in .h (declaration) and .cpp (implementation)? Or am I forced to implement the function in the .h file?

Comment: @Martin it has to be in the header file, since functions with deduced return types can only be called once their definition has been seen. Note that I've only used them to reduce repetition, you could very well use explicit return types. However, since these are function templates, they have the same requirement as well so that doesn't buy you anything.